# How to understand this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, calendar

```
def event_calendar_options
    { 
      :year => @year,
      :month => @month,
      :event_strips => @event_strips,
      :month_name_text => I18n.localize(@shown_month, :format => "%B %Y"),
      :previous_month_text => "<< " + month_link(@shown_month.prev_month),
      :next_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.next_month) + " >>"
    }
end

def event_calendar
  calendar event_calendar_options do |args|
    event = args[:event]
    %(<a href="/events/#{event.id}" title="#{h(event.name)}">#{h(event.name)}</a>)
  end
end
```

Here the whole event_calendar_options is enclosed by {}, so does it simply return the hash table?

Secondly, why event_calendar_options, a module method, can be passed as a parameter to calendar?

Comment: It can be passed as a parameter because it returns the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they're part of the same class (e.g. controller or model), `event_calendar_options` can be called by `event_calendar`. This is common practice within classes. Even if they're not, they can be declared as public and called by other classes as well (which is less common).

And, yes, `event_calendar_options` returns the hash table. In ruby, the final statement will be returned unless a `return` statement is supplied. In this case, it will return a hash table that will be iterated over by the `event_calendar` method.

Comment: Then why bother to use a class around hash instead of just defining a hash directly?

Comment: It's not a class around the hash, it's a method. Since we're in the context of a class (either a controller or a model), how would we go about defining a hash in any other way than defining a method?

Comment: depa is correct. It is a method, and we couldn't understand the motives of the author without asking them directly. Perhaps it is used in multiple methods or called from other classes? If so, doing it like this would be considered a DRY approach.